# How do I import materials, assets, textures to asset browser that are not .blend files?

Tags: materials, blend-files, asset-browser

I have a huge folder of materials I collected over the course of my blender journey and I want them to appear in the asset library so it's easy for me to pick them and apply. But they are not .blend files and are rather the entire material folder with all the maps in them. how do I make it so that they are and easily accessible from the library menu.

Reference Pics:

[image]

[image]

So the first pic is the folder I am trying to import in my asset library and the second pci is the only available materials I can see.. Is there a addon or something which can automate this process for me...

Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hello ! Can you elaborate on the contents of the folders ? raster textures ? the asset browser can only display assets that have been marked in blend files, nothing else

Comment: These are textures we download from sites like polyhaven etc, with all the maps included... They are simply materials, and some assets too,. @Gorgious, do we have a ability to append them all to a blend file and have it in the asset browser?